# How to replace a part of email domain string in Java

Tags: java, regex

I have an email for eg - john.doe@ny.ps.com or john.doe@ma.ps.com and I want to replace it with john.doe@ps.com for all the emails specifically If they have a prefix before ps.

So far I tried

```
final String string = "john.doe@ny.ps.com";
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\@[^.ps]*");
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);    
final String result = matcher.replaceAll("");
```

But the final result is
john.doe.ps.com and not john.doe@ps.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in a **single replacement**.

Search using this regex:

```
(?<=@)(?:[^.]+\.)*(?=ps\.)
```

and replace with empty string.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/BLtONG/1)

**Java Code:**

```
final String string = "john.doe@ny.ps.com";
result = string.replaceFirst("(?<=@)(?:[^\\n.]+\\.)*(?=ps\\.)", "");
//=> john.doe@ps.com
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?<=@)`: Lookbehind to assert that we have `@` before the current position
- `(?:[^.]+\.)*`: Match 1+ of non-dot characters followed by a dot. Repeat this group 0 or more times.
  -`(?=ps\.)`: Lookahead to assert that we have `ps.` ahead of the current position

Answer (score 0):

I made it work by adding @.

```
final String result = matcher.replaceAll("@");
```